# What reference should I use for 'Data.ValueRange'?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, assemblies, google-sheets-api

I'm following a [guide](https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291) to write output data from Visual Studio into a google spreadsheet.

At the end of the guide there is a code block that I pasted inside my project:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using System.IO;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using WikipediaTests.Foundation_Class;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;

namespace AutomationProjects
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass : TestFoundation
    {
        public class SpreadSheetConnector
        {
        //Codeblock from guide pasted here!
        }
        [Test]
        public void test1()
        {
         //Test case 1. Do XYZ...
        }
    }
}
```

In the code block included in the [guide](https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291) there is a section about creating a list and passing data into it:

```
 // Pass in your data as a list of a list (2-D lists are equivalent to the 2-D spreadsheet structure)
            public string UpdateData(List<IList<object>> data)
            {
                String range = "My Tab Name!A1:Y";
                string valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED";

                // The new values to apply to the spreadsheet.
                List<Data.ValueRange> updateData = new List<Data.ValueRange>();
                var dataValueRange = new Data.ValueRange();
                dataValueRange.Range = range;
                dataValueRange.Values = data;
                updateData.Add(dataValueRange);

                Data.BatchUpdateValuesRequest requestBody = new Data.BatchUpdateValuesRequest();
                requestBody.ValueInputOption = valueInputOption;
                requestBody.Data = updateData;

                var request = _sheetsService.Spreadsheets.Values.BatchUpdate(requestBody, _spreadsheetId);

                Data.BatchUpdateValuesResponse response = request.Execute();
                // Data.BatchUpdateValuesResponse response = await request.ExecuteAsync(); // For async 

                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
            }
```

The problem is that I get an error for the 'Data.ValueRange' and the 'Data.BatchUpdateValuesRequest' :

```
CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I tried adding "System.Data" as a assembly reference to my project and then added it at the top (`using`). But it did not remove the error.

'Data.' seems to belong to "Google.Apis.Sheets.v4" but I have already added that reference as the guide instructed.

The only fix that gets rid of the error is adding `Google.Apis.Sheets.v4` before every 'Data.' like this:
`List<Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data.ValueRange>`

But when I run my tests the output does not get exported to my spreadsheet. So I'm assuming this is not the correct solution. And also I'm assuming that the [guide](https://medium.com/@williamchislett/writing-to-google-sheets-api-using-net-and-a-services-account-91ee7e4a291) should have included this in the code block if it was necessary.

Could there be some other reference about 'Data' I need?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Sheets_1_1v4_1_1Data_1_1ValueRange.html), the ValueRange Class depends of Sheets.v4.Data, so you should add:

`using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;`

Also, change:

`List<Data.ValueRange> updateData = new List<Data.ValueRange>();`

to:

`List<ValueRange> updateData = new List<ValueRange>();`

Comment: I tried adding `using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;` but it did not remove the error under `Data`. 

`using Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.Data;` gets greyed out when I add it, so I'm guessing it's not used for any part of the code.

Comment: I will take another look. Meanwhile, you could try doing the [Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet) and see how it goes.